# O content Model aparece no meu index ao usar cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Meus `index.cpt` e `Layout.cpt` estão vazios. Mas no navegador, o meu index aparece com o conteúdo do meu Model:

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array('title' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'), 'body' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'));

}
```

Como consertar isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a URL que você está usando para acessar a página?

Comment: 127.0.0.1/Posts/Posts A tradução ficou meio ruim, na realidade o que quis dizer é que limpei o meu layout, porém o conteúdo da minha classe model fica aparecendo no meu index

Comment: O nome da sua aplicação é `Posts`, você tem um `PostsController` e dentro deste, uma *action* `index()`? É possível colocar o conteúdo desta *action*? Talvez seja um problema no próprio interpretador PHP. Algum outro arquivo PHP (sem mesmo estar no CakePHP) é exibido normalmente?

Comment: <?php class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

    public function index() {
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

Comment: Consegui resolver! foi uma bobagem, apenas comentei a linha  $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));

Comment: Se puder posta a solução abaixo, como resposta, para ajudar quem possa ter o mesmo problema. É um problema estranho, nunca vi acontecer antes!